# Cant connect to my SQL database

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

So I'm having an issue connecting to MySQL with Java.
Heres my code:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;


public class DBAccess {
    private String Host;
    private String User;
    private String Password;

    public DBAccess() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Password = "password";
    Host = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/worlddb";
    User = "root";
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    Connection connect = DriverManager.getConnection(Host,User,Password);
        System.out.println("Connected!"); 
    }
    public void RetreiveData(){

    }
    public void ChangeData(){
    }

}
```

The error that I'm getting is Exception in thread "main"

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'worlddb'
```

http://postimg.org/image/593stjvjx/
in mySQL workbench, my connection name is "worlddb"
hostname is Liquidus(which is the localhost)

- socket is MySQL
- Port: 3306

Why is this?

Comment: Maybe try to add :3306 to your host
jdbc:mysql://host:port/database

Comment: Thats the standard port so shouldnt be needed. allthough, cant hurt to define it neither right :)

Comment: That's true :), you can also check if you granted the access to your user.

Comment: Instead of using throws, catch the exception in order to get full stacktrace, it could be useful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a difference between name of connection and name of Database,try **world**, **test** or **sakila** from schemas in the picture.

Answer (score 2):

```
connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/worlddb?" +"user=root&password=password");
```

Try this, I have a connection to mysql db with same connection, you just add `?` after the name of the db.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the database what you have mentioned in `Host = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/worlddb";` i.e **worlddb** is correct or not.
The name of the database here is **CASE SENSITIVE!** So, if you try to connect using a database name like "**test2**" instead of "**Test2**" , you will get the

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'test2'
```

Also try using port number too

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/worlddb", "root", "password");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this it's hopeful for you:

```
Connection con = null;
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
con =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/worlddb","root","password");
```

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/593stjvjx/
This is a link to a screenshot of my workbench.
maybe you will see something that I don't.

Comment: I think not have a database name as worlddb or database not present.please check database and tables

Comment: I think your databases are: 'sakila', 'test' and 'world'. Try to connect on one of them and let us know how it went

Answer (score 1):

In the above code, port number is missing.

```
connection = connection=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/worlddb","root", "password");
```

default port number of mysql is 3306

Comment: If you are commenting on somebody else's answer, please use a comment instead of an additional answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Take care to not have white spaces and use `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the DB server is not case sensitive? I mean maybe on the DB server the DB name is WorldDb and you are trying to connect to it by using worlddb (all low lecters)..
Try to use the same name or to configure MySQL to be case insensitive

Comment: mysql is case insensitive

Comment: I tried to add a picture of the database from my workbench, but I dont have enough rep.
It says Connection Name: worlddb

Comment: @Charafjra as far as I know MySQL default installation on *NIX servers is case sensitive

Answer (score 0):

Write

```
"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/worlddb"
```

instead of

```
"jdbc:mysql://localhost/worlddb"
```

Answer (score 0):

Charaf jra was right i had the same issue.
 your schema(schema = Database) is listed as   **Host = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/worlddb";**
      If you look at the schemas in the pic you posted https://postimg.cc/image/593stjvjx/
the schema(Database) is **world**.