# MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database Error

Tags: mysql, jdbc

A very strange issue. I have a Mysql server hosted on my local desktop. I can connect to it via mysql terminal. I have a schema named phoenix.

When I try to connect to it via jdbc below code

```
String  JDBC_USER = "root"
String JDBC_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/phoenix"
String  JDBC_PASSWORD = "root";
String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER).newInstance();
DriverManager.getConnection(JDBC_URL, JDBC_USER, JDBC_PASSWORD);
```

It says

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database phoenix
```

Any help on this will be appreciated.

Comment: An earlier similar question might have the answer you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20324476/cant-connect-to-my-sql-database

Comment: I have checked name of database.It matches with Case. Also tried removing the port number from connect string.Also tried with                                        Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);